# Store templated objects as member objects

Tags: c++, performance

suppose you have some code like this:

```
struct Manager
{
  template <class T> 
  void doSomething(T const& t)
  {
    Worker<T> worker;
    worker.work(t);
  }
};
```

A "Manager" object is created once and called with a few diffent types "T", but each type T is called many times. This might be, in a simplified form, like

```
Manager manager;
const int N = 1000;
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
  manager.doSomething<int>(3);
  manager.doSomething<char>('x');
  manager.doSomething<float>(3.14);
}
```

Now profiling revealed that **constructing a `Worker<T>` is a time-costly operation and it should be avoided to construct it N times** (within `doSomething<T>`). For thread-safety reasons it is ok to have one `Worker<int>`, one `Worker<char>` and `Worker<float>` per "Manager", but not one `Worker<int>` for all Managers. So usually I would make "worker" a member variable. But how could I do this in the code above? (I do not know in advance which "T"s will be used).

I have found a solution using a std::map, but it is not fully typesafe and certainly not very elegant. Can you suggest a typesafe way without constructing `Worker<T>` more often than once per "T" without virtual methods?

(please note that Worker is not derived from any template-argument free base class).

Thanks for any solution!

Comment: Sounds like a job for a tuple, though I'm not familiar with the syntax, so I can't provide an example.

Comment: What about making your worker class a singleton to have only one instance per class? (since Worker<int>, Worker<float>, ..., or different classes, it is possible) - Worker<T>::instance_get().work(t)

Comment: If you are happy to use `boost::mpl`, check out my own question and answer, you may be able to adapt it to your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798169/is-there-a-way-to-break-out-of-boostmpl-for-each

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like a `std::map<std::type_info,shared_ptr<void> >` like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

// exposition only:
template <typename T>
struct Worker {
    void work( const T & ) {}
};

// wrapper around type_info (could use reference_wrapper,
// but the code would be similar) to make it usable as a map<> key:
struct TypeInfo {
    const type_info & ti;
    /*implicit*/ TypeInfo( const type_info & ti ) : ti( ti ) {}
};

// make it LessComparable (could spcialise std::less, too):
bool operator<( const TypeInfo & lhs, const TypeInfo & rhs ) {
    return lhs.ti.before( rhs.ti );
}

struct Manager
{
    map<TypeInfo,shared_ptr<void> > m_workers;
    template <class T> 
    Worker<T> * findWorker()
    {
        const map<TypeInfo,shared_ptr<void> >::const_iterator
        it = m_workers.find( typeid(T) );
        if ( it == m_workers.end() ) {
            const shared_ptr< Worker<T> > nworker( new Worker<T> );
            m_workers[typeid(T)] = nworker;
            return nworker.get();
        } else {
            return static_cast<Worker<T>*>( it->second.get() );
        }
    }
    template <typename T>
    void doSomething( const T & t ) {
        findWorker<T>()->work( t );
    }
};

int main() {

    Manager m;
    m.doSomething( 1 );
    m.doSomething( 1. );

    return 0;
}
```

This is typesafe because we use `type_info` as an index into the map. Also, the workers are properly deleted even though they're in `shared_ptr<void>`s because the deleter is copied from the original `shared_ptr<Worker<T> >`s, and that one calls the proper constructor. It also doesn't use virtual functions, although all type erasure (and this is one) uses something like virtual functions somewhere. Here, it's in `shared_ptr`.

Factoring the template-independent code from `findWorker` into a non-template function to reduce code bloat is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Thanks to all commenters who pointed out the mistake of using `type_info` as the key directly.

Comment: This does seem to meet all the OP's requirements.

Comment: @mmutz: type_info is not assignable. Did you try compiling this?

Comment: @mmutz: `type_info` is also not required to provide `operator<`.

Comment: @Emile: `type_info` has the `before` method, so you can introduce a comparision functor if it doesn't provide `operator<`.

Comment: @Emile: I was under the impression that `less<type_info>` was required to be properly specialised by the standard, but I guess I was wrong. And while I don't need assignment of `type_info` I do need it to be copy-constructable, which it also isn't. A small wrapper type fixes this. Fully compilable sample code in edit. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @mmutz: You also can't safely delete your `Worker<T>`s because their type end up being erased when stored in `shared_ptr<void>`.

Comment: @Emile: while their type is erased, they still have the correct deleter.

Comment: @mmutz: +1 I didn't know shared_ptr copied the deleter. Good to know! With `shared_ptr<void>`, you avoid virtual function call overhead for `Worker::work`. Nice.

Comment: @mmutz: thanks a lot! I had a similar solution with void* instead of shared_ptr<void> and some other mechanisms to call the correct deleter. Now the code looks *much* better!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `std::vector` of `boost::variant`s or `boost::any`s as member of your class. And append to it any worker you want.

**EDIT:** The code bellow will explain how

```
struct Manager
{
  std::vector<std::pair<std::type_info, boost::any> > workers;
  template <class T> 
  void doSomething(T const& t)
  {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < workers.size(); ++i)
        if(workers[i].first == typeid(T))
            break;
    if(i == workers.size())
        workers.push_back(std::pair<std::type_info, boost::any>(typeid(T).name(), Worker<T>());
    any_cast<T>(workers[i]).work(t);
  }
};
```

Comment: This is much more elegant than the other solutions. The vector made me cringe at first but how large is it going to get in practice?

Comment: I also thought that the num of differen workers is small so it's ok to store them in vector (or maybe in list).

Answer (score 2):

I was already working on an answer similar to mmutz's by time he posted his. Here's a complete solution that compiles and runs under GCC 4.4.3. It uses RTTI and polymorphism to lazily construct `Worker<T>`s and store them in a map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>

struct BaseWorker
{
    virtual ~BaseWorker() {}
    virtual void work(const void* x) = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct Worker : public BaseWorker
{
    Worker()
    {
        /* Heavyweight constructor*/
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << " constructor\n";
    }

    void work(const void* x) {doWork(*static_cast<const T*>(x));}

    void doWork(const T& x)
        {std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "::doWork(" << x << ")\n";}
};

struct TypeofLessThan
{
    bool operator()(const std::type_info* lhs, const std::type_info* rhs) const
        {return lhs->before(*rhs);}
};

struct Manager
{
    typedef std::map<const std::type_info*, BaseWorker*, TypeofLessThan> WorkerMap;

    ~Manager()
    {
        // Delete all BaseWorkers in workerMap_
        WorkerMap::iterator it;
        for (it = workerMap_.begin(); it != workerMap_.end(); ++it)
            delete it->second;
    }

    template <class T>
    void doSomething(T const& x)
    {
        WorkerMap::iterator it = workerMap_.find(&typeid(T));
        if (it == workerMap_.end())
        {
            it = workerMap_.insert(
                std::make_pair(&typeid(T), new Worker<T>) ).first;
        }
        Worker<T>* worker = static_cast<Worker<T>*>(it->second);
        worker->work(&x);
    }

    WorkerMap workerMap_;
};

int main()
{
    Manager manager;
    const int N = 10;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
      manager.doSomething<int>(3);
      manager.doSomething<char>('x');
      manager.doSomething<float>(3.14);
    }
}
```

`map<std::type_info, BaseWorker*>` doesn't work because `type_info` is not copy-constructible. I had do use `map<const std::type_info*, BaseWorker*>`. I just need to check that typeid(T) is guaranteed to always return the same reference (I think it is).

---

It doesn't matter whether or not `typeid(T)` returns the same reference, because I always use `type_info::before` do to all comparisons.

Comment: Is it safe to take the address of `type_info`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70ky2y6k(v=vs.80).aspx says "construct a (temporary) object" and I really don't know how to read that statement.

Comment: @Emile: you're not passing `t` to `work()` in `doSomething()`.

Comment: I don't believe this works, because the virtual base method work() is never implemented this way, right?

Comment: @Philipp: You're right, it doesn't work. I "fixed" it without bothering to recompile it. I don't know if I can even make it work at all. I might have to scrap this answer.

Comment: Fixed my code and actually tested it this time. I used type erasure to get around the problem of not being able to declare a virtual template function.

Comment: Made another tweak to avoid virtual function call overhead for `Worker<T>::work`.

Answer (score 0):

something like this will work:

```
struct Base { };
template<class T> struct D : public Base { Manager<T> *ptr; };
...
struct Manager {
  ...
Base *ptr;
};
```