# How to get a type relative to a runtime index?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

Let's say I have a `boost::mpl::list< A, B, C ...>`.

How do I access one of those types **given an index value at runtime**? Is it even possible?

Comment: Please provide some context of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: May be you'll find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798169/is-there-a-way-to-break-out-of-boostmpl-for-each

Comment: @Emile Cornier> Whatever the context, mpl::list is a type container that provide compile-time type-container semantic. So the questions is clear : I got this compile-time list of types and I want to get the type that is at a specific index, but I got the index only at runtime, not compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html

you basically have to iterate over the entire list and introduce some sort of conditional:
eg:

```
struct F {
    void operator(T &t) {
        if (i_ == index) ...
        ++i;
    }
    int index = ...;
    int i_ = 0;
};
for_each< L >( F(index) );
```

Comment: I don't see how that bare link answers the question.

Comment: You know what? I posted this question after having checked all possibilities, and I had to leave my workplace. Once out I got this exact idea. TT___TT I guess I was too tired.
Thanks anyway, that confirm it.